# C# equal values, error in one of them

Tags: c#

I'm trying to execute the following code:

```
X_coordinates[i] = Decimal.Parse(g);
```

g is a string that was split from a longer string and has a value of 10,40572555349526687. Running the code gives me this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

However, when changing the code like this:

```
                    string theSameNumber = "10,40572555349526687";
                    if (theSameNumber == g)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("They are equal");
                    }
                    X_coordinates[i] = Decimal.Parse(theSameNumber);
```

The code executes without any errors, and I get the message in the console saying they are equal. As soon as I change theSameNumber back to g I get the same error as before, even though they are supposed to be the same thing. Can anyone explain why this might happen? 
(The "," is interpreted as a decimal point because of regional differences)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] - it's hard to tell what's going on just from these snippets.

Comment: Try providing `NumberStyles`, something like `decimal.Parse("10,40572555349526687", NumberStyles.Currency);`

Comment: Where and how are you declaring x_coordinates?

Comment: In the same while loop, just above the piece of code I posted:decimal [] X_coordinates = new decimal [Int32.Parse(coordinates_count)];

Answer (score 0):

I think that a decimal number should contain a period (.) instead of a comma (,).

```
10,40572555349526687
```

should be

```
10.40572555349526687
```